# Parse numbers from large text, possibly without regex (performance critical)

Tags: c#, parsing, text-processing

I'm extremely familiar with regex before you all start answering with variations of: /d+

I want to know if there are alternatives to regex for parsing numbers out of a large text file.

I'm parsing through tons of huge files and need to do some group/location analysis on the positions of keywords. I'm now at the point where i need to start finding groups of numbers as well nested closely to my content of interest. I want to avoid regex if at all possible because this needs to be a speedy process.

It is possible to take chunks of a file to inspect for the numbers of interest. That however would require more work and add hard coded limits for searching. (i'd like to avoid this)

I'm open to any suggestions.

### UPDATE

Sorry for the lack of sample data. For HIPAA reasons I'd rather not even consider scrambling the text and posting it.

A great substitute would be the HTML source of any stackoverflow.com question page. Imagine I needed to grab the reputation (score) of all people that posted an answer to a question. This also means that the comma (,) is needed as well. I can't remove the html to simplify the content because I'm using some density analysis to weed out unrelated content. Removing the HTML would mix content too close together.

Comment: I"m not totally clear on the ask here.  Are you familiar with the .IndexOf method (e.g. fulltext.IndexOf(teststring))?  If so, what more do you need to do?

Comment: Problem is, OP indicates very large files, IndexOf suggestes that you need the entire file in memory, as it can't understand boundaries - IE it wont know if the number ran on from the previous block, or procedes to the next block - this is why I'd like to see the sort of data OP is trying to process.

Comment: I need to be able to look for integers in a large text file. I won't know what the numbers will be so IndexOf() is not exactly an option.

Comment: Please give more detail about the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the file is some sort of SGML, then I don't know of any method (which is not to say there isn't, I just don't know of one)

However, it's not to say that you can't create your own parser; you could eliminate some of the overheads of the .Net regex library by writing something that only finds ranges of numbers.

Fundamentally, I guess that that's all any library would do, at the most basic level.

Might help if you can post a sample of the sort of data you'll be processing?

Comment: I was thinking something along the same lines. The text is a mixture of HTML and XML

Comment: In that case, you could use something like the Html action pack to at least reduce the area you're searching.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but wouldn't parsing a file as HTML/XML be just as costly as scanning through the entire file to find all numeric sequences in the first place?  In both cases, you're scanning through the entire file, only in the first case you're scanning to parse out the HTML/XML structure, which are more complex than simply finding the numeric sequences.

Comment: It may well be, I was just expounding on possible solutions that don't involve Regex. The one thing about using a HTML/XML parser is that you could at least discount a lot of raw-content that would be in tag names and attributes.

Comment: In a way you answered the question. You didn't know of a way other than regex either other than writing a custom parser. thnx!